# How to keep two different header (h2) tags on one line?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to make it so I have a person's name and the date on one line, though the name aligned left and the date aligned right.

```
<h2>Firstname Surname</h2><text align="right"><h2>Date</h2>
```

The above seems to align them both, but puts them on separate lines.
I assume this is because I'm using two different h2 tags, though if I leave them as one:

```
<h2>Firstname Surname <text align="right"> Date</h2>
```

I get all the text on one line, but with no aligning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
<h2>Firstname Surname <span style="float:right;">Date</span></h2>
```

Comment: The float:right should be in a css file, not inline

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options

if you want two tags, you could have one floated left, the other floated right

if you don't want floats you could set them to display inline, give both a 50% width and set the text-align css prop

Another option would be to have the right aligned text in a span inside the h2 and float that right

N.b. don't forget to clear your floats.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<h2 style="float:left">Firstname Surname</h2><span><h2>Date</h2></span>
```

Comment: why the empty unclosed span tag? its not valid

Comment: no problem, sorry but having a block level element inside a inline element is also invalid, you'd want <h2><span></span></h2>

Answer (score 0):

## Use the power of css!

I've used `display:inline-block;`,as (rather than floating your elements) - it makes them much easier to handle (since floating involves extra css to 'clear' them - a problem most people fail to do).

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>FIZZ</h2>
<h2>BUZZ</h2>
```

The option of 'floating' elements can be seen here (along with the 'clearing' problem) and hence why using the display option would be more beneficial to you:

```css
.floated {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="floated">FOO</h2>
<h2 class="floated">BAR</h2>
<div >i'm more text in the next line which could've been avoided</div>
```